# Confirm Calculation for Data Transfer

Tags: data-transfer, calc

I would like to confirm my calculation for data transfer:

Assume, I have 1 PB of data and a network bandwidth of 1 Gbps, how long will it take to transfer the data.

I have the following calculation:

1 PB = 1,000,000 GB (decimal)

Therefore, it will take 1,000,000 / (60 * 60 * 24) = 11.57 days to transfer the data.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be (1,000,000 * 8) / (60 * 60 * 24) = (11.57 * 8) .

Since 1B = 8 bit

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that.